# How to check a process is running in monit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, monit

```
check process myproc with pidfile /opt/management/myproc.pid
            start program = "/etc/init.d/myproc start"
            stop  program = "/etc/init.d/myproc stop"
            if 3 restarts within 3 cycles then timeout
            mode  active
            group local
```

Above is monit file for myproc. When I clone my vm, sometimes the myproc.pid file is exist but actual process is not running in the cloned vm. In this case, monit still thinks myproc is running and not attempting to start my process in newly cloned vm.
Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: I see different process is running with myproc.pid number. That's why monit thinks myproc.pid is still valid!